# "Error: unable to open database" when creating sqlite3 database in terminal

Tags: command-line, database, sqlite

The other questions I've seen deal with this have to do with creating databses through Django or some other Python framework. I am simply trying to create a database with `$sqlite3 database.db`. It opens up the sqlite console, but when I type `.schema`, I get `Error: unable to open database "database.db": unable to open database file`, and then get booted from the database. There's no `database.db` file leftover.

I cannot make sense of this.

Comment: Can you give us the exact console output ?

Comment: That error message is the only console output I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database file is not created until you actually add table(s).  Try adding a table using:

```
sqlite> create table [table name]([field] [type]);
sqlite> .quit
```

Then you should have a database file created.